# socket.gethostbyname unable to find local hostname after updating to mac osx sierra

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sockets, homebrew, macos-sierra

After updating to OS Sierra, I tried running my local test suite with `rspec spec`, this immediately broke giving this stack trace:

```
Coverage report generated for RSpec to /Users/October/Documents/code/clients-api/coverage. 38 / 101 LOC (37.62%) covered.
/Users/October/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@clients-api/gems/bundler-1.13.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:94:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error while trying to load the gem 'torid'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)
Gem Load Error is: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
Backtrace for gem load error is:
/Users/October/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@clients-api/gems/torid-1.2.4/lib/torid/generator.rb:73:in `gethostbyname'
/Users/October/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@clients-api/gems/torid-1.2.4/lib/torid/generator.rb:73:in `create_node_id'
/Users/October/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@clients-api/gems/torid-1.2.4/lib/torid/generator.rb:79:in `<class:Generator>'
/Users/October/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@clients-api/gems/torid-1.2.4/lib/torid/generator.rb:21:in `<module:Torid>'
/Users/October/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@clients-api/gems/torid-1.2.4/lib/torid/generator.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/October/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@clients-api/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/Users/October/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@clients-api/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/Users/October/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@clients-api/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/Users/October/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@clients-api/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/Users/October/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@clients-api/gems/torid-1.2.4/lib/torid.rb:22:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/October/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@clients-api/gems/bundler-1.13.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `require'
/Users/October/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@clients-api/gems/bundler-1.13.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/Users/October/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@clients-api/gems/bundler-1.13.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `each'
/Users/October/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@clients-api/gems/bundler-1.13.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block in require'
/Users/October/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@clients-api/gems/bundler-1.13.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `each'
/Users/October/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@clients-api/gems/bundler-1.13.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `require'
/Users/October/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@clients-api/gems/bundler-1.13.2/lib/bundler.rb:106:in `require'
/Users/October/Documents/code/clients-api/config/application.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/October/Documents/code/clients-api/config/environment.rb:2:in `require'
/Users/October/Documents/code/clients-api/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/October/Documents/code/clients-api/spec/spec_helper.rb:6:in `require'
/Users/October/Documents/code/clients-api/spec/spec_helper.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/October/Documents/code/clients-api/spec/consumers/postback_notifier_consumer_spec.rb:1:in `require_relative'
/Users/October/Documents/code/clients-api/spec/consumers/postback_notifier_consumer_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/October/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@clients-api/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1226:in `load'
/Users/October/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@clients-api/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1226:in `block in load_spec_files'
/Users/October/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@clients-api/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1224:in `each'
/Users/October/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@clients-api/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1224:in `load_spec_files'
/Users/October/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@clients-api/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:97:in `setup'
/Users/October/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@clients-api/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:85:in `run'
/Users/October/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@clients-api/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:70:in `run'
/Users/October/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@clients-api/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:38:in `invoke'
/Users/October/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@clients-api/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/October/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@clients-api/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
/Users/October/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@clients-api/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
/Users/October/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@clients-api/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/October/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@clients-api/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

I further investigated inside the `torid` gem to find the block of code that is failing:

```
def self.create_node_id( pid = Process.pid )
    hostname = Socket.gethostbyname( Socket.gethostname ).first
    random   = SecureRandom.hex( 16 )
    FNV.new.fnv1a_64("#{hostname}-#{pid}-#{random}")
 end
```

When I inspected it with byebug:

`(byebug)hostname = Socket.gethostbyname( Socket.gethostname ).first`

=> `(byebug)SocketError Exception: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known`
`nil`

Also `gethostname` does return the correct hostname:

`(byebug)Socket.gethostname`

=> `(byebug) "OctobersMac"`

At this point, I have tried re-installing `homebrew`, `postgres`, `xcode`, `rvm` and `ruby`. I also made sure that my hostname was set to OctobersMac. It gets stranger in the fact that when I check my ports for that hostname, none are open. I set it with `scutil --get HostName` and it returns correctly. I have no firewalls set up either.

I opened two other apps and ran `rspec spec` just to be sure that it wasn't just one app. The first came back with the exact same error and the second got a different error, though I have a feeling it has something to do with the original issue:

```
OctobersMac:community October$ rspec spec
"Railtie has run for Postgis!!!!"
/Users/October/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@community/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `initialize': could not connect to server: Connection refused (PG::ConnectionBad)
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
    from /Users/October/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@ring-community/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `new'
    from /Users/October/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@ring-community/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `connect'
    from /Users/October/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@ring-community/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:242:in `initialize'
    from /Users/October/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@ring-community/gems/activerecord-postgis-adapter-3.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgis_adapter.rb:51:in `initialize'
    from /Users/October/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@ring-community/gems/activerecord-postgis-adapter-3.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgis/create_connection.rb:38:in `new'
    from /Users/October/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@ring-community/gems/activerecord-postgis-adapter-3.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgis/create_connection.rb:38:in `postgis_connection'
    from /Users/October/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@ring-community/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:438:in `new_connection'
```

Does anyone have any idea what is going on here? I'm at the end of my rope and Google doesn't have much on related issues to Mac OsX Sierra. Thank you for any time you can spare towards my issue.

Comment: The issue seems to be language agnostic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39970606/gaierror-errno-8-nodename-nor-servname-provided-or-not-known-with-macos-sie

Comment: You may want to write a C program that does `Socket.gethostbyname( Socket.gethostname )` and see if it works. If not, file a bug to Apple and try to move to `getaddrinfo` from `gethostbyname` - the latter is deprecated. If the C program works, file a bug to Ruby community.

Comment: Here's a C program folks can use to test their name lookups on Sierra https://gist.github.com/copiousfreetime/44a950fb0fa8896450af75f919dbe7f1

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this is a problem with Sierra. The torid gem authors have a [fix](https://github.com/copiousfreetime/torid/commit/5dd4b36f982a846ab9bb7559e96ef8750994790d). In the comment they state:

> MacOS Sierra does not always find the Addrinfo value for the hostname
>   which can cause an error to happen and torid fail to work.

I came across a similar issue with the logstash gem, which has also been [fixed](https://github.com/shadabahmed/logstasher/blob/master/lib/logstasher/railtie.rb). In their code they have a comment (in the default_source method) that states:

```
# NOTE: MacOS Sierra and later are setting `.local`
# hostnames that even as real hostnames without the `.local` part,
# are still unresolvable. One reliable way to get an IP is to
# get all available IP address lists and use the first one.
# This will always be `127.0.0.1`.
```