# gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known (with macOS Sierra)

Tags: python, sockets

socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()) worked well on OS X El Capitan. However, it's not working now after the Mac updated to macOS Sierra.

Thanks!

```
import socket
socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#26>", line 1, in <module>
    socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Comment: Make sure file `/etc/hosts` contains `127.0.0.1 localhost`.

Comment: Thanks! I've checked $ sudo nano /etc/hosts and found 127.0.0.1 localhost already there. Still not working.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: Perhaps the order of the results has changed?   you should print out information from the intermediary calls to see what is going on

Comment: socket.gethostname() works: 'FBLs-MBP.local'.

Comment: And $ ping 'FBLs-MBP.local' leads to ping: cannot resolve FBLs-MBP.local: Unknown host, while ping the IP address works well.

Comment: Related issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39968792/socket-gethostbyname-unable-to-find-local-hostname-after-updating-to-mac-osx-sie

Comment: Still not working. But the problem can now be located: $ ping 'FBLs-MBP.local' leads to ping: cannot resolve FBLs-MBP.local: Unknown host on macOS Sierra. Any ideas about this? Thanks!

Comment: Problem solved. Thanks guys! http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/253817/cannot-ping-my-local-machine

Comment: It turned out that I got the same error, but had not entered a FQDN. After using FQDN this error stopped. (ex. user enters "google" and not "google.com")

Answer (score 50):

There is an answer in OP's comments based on [another question,](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/253817/cannot-ping-my-local-machine)
which requires to edit `/etc/hosts`, i.e `echo 127.0.0.1 $HOSTNAME >> /etc/hosts`.

Alternatively, you can use `socket.gethostbyname('localhost')`, assuming that `localhost` is what you need and it is defined in your `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: Thanks.it works for my mac.

Comment: This worked for me except I needed to replace `$HOSTNAME` with just `$HOST`, i.e `echo 127.0.0.1 $HOST >> /etc/hosts`

Answer (score 16):

Same problem tome.
I change the code to:

```
import socket
socket.gethostbyname("")
```

And it works now.

Comment: I don't think this would work, I don't know the technical reason behind it but when I try this I get '0.0.0.0' on macOS 10.12.2. I presume it's not looking up a hostname and just returns a default value.

Comment: If you want to bind the ip and port for a tcp/http server, '0.0.0.0' is ok for it. But if you just want to get the ip text, gethostbyname is not a good choice.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem today (with MacOS Mojave) and was able to fix it using the [link](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/253817/cannot-ping-my-local-machine) that [@FBL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6952361/fbl) provided in the comments.

Specifically, I just had to go to System Preferences -> Sharing and enable sharing. (I enabled printer sharing). Then I verified it was working via `ping $HOST`. Afterwards, I was able to turn sharing back off and everything (both `ping $HOST` and `python -c 'import socket; print socket.gethostbysocketname(socket.gethostname())`) still worked.

Comment: Enabling sharing via System Preferences worked for me

Comment: Enabling Remote Login sharing via System Preferences worked for me

Answer (score 3):

Rather than using the localhost, use the computer name as specified in /etc/hosts.

For example, /etc/host would have something like this:

```
127.0.0.1 ET02282-MAC.local
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

And in your connection use **"ET02282-MAC.local"**

Answer (score 3):

It seems like a python bug? You need to set the hostname & ipv4 , after this, you can fix it.

```
import socket
hostname = socket.gethostname()
print(hostname)  >> samzong

# make sure do it
!echo "127.0.0.1 samzong" >> /private/etc/hosts
```

Answer (score 1):

Another simple solution is
Go terminal paste sudo nano /etc/hosts
find your ip adress that is needed , IPv4 etc.
add a new line like
190.123.123.3 Yourterminalname.local
it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. I was not able to ping localhost.

> > ping localhost

```
>> error ping: cannot resolve localhost: Unknown host
```

I changed my hosts file.

> > sudo nano /etc/hosts

Add this to the file (use Tab/4 spaces to separate>> 127.0.0.1{tab/4spaces}localhost) Save it and restart the terminal.

> > 127.0.0.1    localhost

To confirm if everything works fine, try pinging your localhost

> > ping localhost

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jupyter notebook or not try this

```
IP4=str(ipaddress.ip_address(8888))
IPAddr = socket.gethostbyname(IP4)
```

don't forget to import ipaddress & socket

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue.

macOS Catalina

Version: 10.15.7

[image]

The solution was::

```
import socket

if env == "PRODUCTION":
    ip_address = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
else:
    ip_address = ""
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, so I used the subprocess command line utility to find the ip address of my machine. The code I used was:

```
from sys import platform
def getIP():
    if platform == "linux" or platform == "linux2":
        # linux
        ip = sb.run(["ipconfig", "getifaddr", "en0"], capture_output=True)
        ...
    elif platform == "darwin":
        # OS X
        ip = sb.run(["ipconfig", "getifaddr", "en0"], capture_output=True)
        ...
    elif platform == "win32":
        # Windows...
        ip = sb.run(["ipconfig", "| findstr /i" "ipv4"],capture_output=True)
        ...
    return ip.stdout.decode()
```

It returns the IPv4 address of my machine and works on Windows, Mac and Linux

Answer (score 0):

If 127.0.0.1 localhost already exists in your /etc/hosts, try to restart MacBook. It helps to me.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of obvious but if you cloned a project that is using an env variable for your port... best to make sure youve actually set up those env variables...