# OSError: [Errno 49] Can't assign requested address

Tags: python, sockets, sensors, ssdp

I am trying to connect a BCG sensor (Murata Sensor) to a wifi network and get data from it. I have configured the sensor in suppose a wifi named "Wifi1" and then I am trying to access the data from the sensor on my Mac which is also connected on Wifi1. The python script first tries finding the node using ssdpSearch function and then executes the later code. Here is the entire code :

```
import socket 
import time 
import datetime

REPEAT = 10

def ssdpSearch():   
    print("Starting SSDP Search. 10 seconds.")   
    UDP_IP = '<broadcast>'   
    UDP_PORT = 2000   
    UDP_MESSAGE = '{"type":"SCS-DISCOVER","hostname":"Host-SCS"}'   
    networks = socket.gethostbyname_ex(socket.gethostname())[2] # Find all networks (i.e, wifi, wired)   
    sockets = []   
    for net in networks: # Connect to all networks
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
        sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1) # Allow broadcast
        sock.bind((net, UDP_PORT)) # Connect
        sock.settimeout(1.0) # Set timeout (if no answer when reading)
        sockets.append(sock) # Save "sock" to sockets   
        timeStart = time.time()   
        devices = []   
        print('Found devices:')   
        time.sleep(0.1) 
        while time.time() - timeStart < REPEAT:
            for sock in sockets:
              try:
                sock.sendto(UDP_MESSAGE.encode(), (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
                data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
                data = data.decode()
                data = data[1:].split(',')
                if data[0] == '"type":"SCS-NOTIFY"': # Only accept correct responses
                  oldDevice = 0
                  # print(data)
                  for dev in devices:
                    if dev[0] == data[1]:
                      oldDevice = 1
                  if not oldDevice:
                    devices.append([data[1],data[2]]) # Save found devices
                    print('\t' + data[1] + ' ' + data[2])
              except:
                1
            time.sleep(0.2) 
            if not len(devices):
                print('\t No devices found.')
                print('')
                for sock in sockets:
                    sock.close()

def readLine(s):
# Function to read status from BCG data
    line = s.recv(1024).decode()
    return line

def main():
    print('BCG Data Logger \n Logs either raw data or BCG algorithm data to a file \ depending on configured mode.')
    # Open file
    IP = input('Insert IP address (empty for SSDP): ')
    while len(IP) == 0:
        ssdpSearch()
        IP = input('Insert IP address (empty for SSDP): ')
    PORT = 8080
    filename = 'logged_data_' + str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')) + '.txt'
    fid = open(filename,'w')
    print('')
    print('Starting to read data. Press \"ctrl+c\" to quit.')
    while True:
        try:
            s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            s.settimeout(10)
            s.connect((IP, PORT))
            while True: #
                data = readLine(s)
                print(data,)
                fid.write(data)
        except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
            print('Exiting program.')
            fid.close()
            break
        except (socket.timeout):
            print('Timed out, reconnecting.')
        except socket.error as msg:
            print(msg)
            print('Trying to reconnect.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In the output it is first asking me the IP address which I have no clue which IP address is it asking. We may leave it blank if it is SSDP so if I leave it blank it gives following error:

```
>Insert IP address (empty for SSDP): 
>Starting SSDP Search. 10 seconds.
>Traceback (most recent call last):
>File "DataCollection.py", line 91, in <module>
>main()
>File "DataCollection.py", line 64, in main
>ssdpSearch()
>File "DataCollection.py", line 17, in ssdpSearch
>networks = socket.gethostbyname_ex(socket.gethostname())[2] # Find all networks (i.e, wifi, wired)
>socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Can anyone help me out to understand this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gaierror: \[Errno 8\] nodename nor servname provided, or not known (with macOS Sierra)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39970606/gaierror-errno-8-nodename-nor-servname-provided-or-not-known-with-macos-sie)

Comment: What is socket.gethostbyname_ex(socket.gethostname())[2] returning? add a debug print stmt.

Comment: @TemporaWolf The problem in my case is I am inside a proxy network of my company and I cannot handle this problem as freely as the other guys have handeled it.

Comment: @Gregory it returns the IP address of my machine

Comment: @KathanVyas Hmm, that's odd. The error you're getting is saying you're NOT getting back a hostname. Step through the function: (1) see what you get with: socket.gethostname() then (2) see what  socket.gethostbyname_ex(socket.gethostname()) returns.

Comment: @Gregory 
socket.gethostname() gives the name of my MAC (MACC0XXXXXXXX)
socket.gethostbyname_ex(socket.gethostname()) gives me an IP address (x.x.x.x) which I checked is basically IP address of my MAC.