# pyzabbix Zabbix sender

Tags: python, zabbix

I am looking to send a few items to zabbix using Zabbix-Sender function of pyzabbix. As a test I am running the below code -

```
from pyzabbix import ZabbixMetric, ZabbixSender, ZabbixResponse
metrics = []
m= ZabbixMetric('mme01', 'TEST', 20)
metrics.append(m)
ZabbixSender('10.46.224.5').send(metrics)
```

I made this snippet after reading the document - https://py-zabbix.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sender.html

When I run the snippet I get the error -

```
AttributeError: 'ConnectionRefusedError' object has no attribute 'msg'
```

I have verified IP connectivity

Can Anyone help ?

Comment: I decided to bypass the module - pyzabbix and decided to use the raw zabbix sender utility. Works great.

Answer (score 3):

there is a mess in modules names.

it seems you call 'other' pyzabbix module who has not needed methods.
first, remove all zabbix-related modules:
`pip list | grep zabbix; pip uninstall ...`

and then install pyzabbix:
`pip install py-zabbix`.

this should help.

UPDATED:
I dug deeper and figured out that the `AttributeError: 'ConnectionRefusedError' object has no attribute 'msg'` exception caused by old module version bug, which has been fixed [here](https://github.com/adubkov/py-zabbix/pull/99). update it with pip or manually.

new bug I have faced is `[Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known` [caused by socket lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39970606/gaierror-errno-8-nodename-nor-servname-provided-or-not-known-with-macos-sie) and can be fixed pointing to zabbix server/proxy IP address instead of DNS name

Answer (score 2):

I decided to bypass the module - pyzabbix and decided to use the raw zabbix sender utility. Works great.

For other folks my solution relies on a file with values that need to be sent to zabbix.

Sample file -

```
"mme01" TEST 1544729668 44
```

The use the utility -

```
/opt/zabbix-proxy/bin/zabbix_sender -vv -z 10.43.X.X -T  -i mme_file.txt
```

Replace with path of your zabbix_sender and the zabbix server IP.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on some machines of mine. At that time I refactored my code to use zabbix_sender and it worked great.

After some time I found out the issue was related to pip repository corruption. I ended up reinstalling all the packages with this option:

```
pip install --ignore-installed <package>
```

apparently the issue was fixed, but I still have no idea why it occurred on some manchines and not in anothers.