# FastAPI/asyncpg/Postgresql 200 request per second

Tags: python, postgresql, python-asyncio, fastapi

I have a simple Flask application which calls FastApi with route /api,
FastAPI calls Postgresql Database.
Need to achieve 200 request/second  (insertions through Flask => FastAPI => DB).

**Flask**

To run it I use gunicorn

```
gunicorn --worker-class gevent  --workers 2 --threads 50 --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 main_api:app
```

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/api/mt_retailprice', methods=['POST'])
# @jwt_required()
def mt_retailprice():

    try:

        request_data = request.get_json()
             
        _write_to_database(request_data)

        return data

    except Exception as e:
        logging.error("Prediction is failed, review that json sent in the body is correct.Exception %s has happened", e)
        return e

def _write_to_database(data):
    
    api_url = f'http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/'
    return  write_sql(api_url, data)


def write_sql(url, data):
    """
    Makes a POST request to a specific URL
    """
    try:
        headers = {
            'Accept-Language': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
        payload = json.dumps(data)
        return requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(e)


def main():
    configure_logging()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**FastAPI**

```
class Database():

    async def create_pool(self):
        self.pool = await asyncpg.create_pool(user=username, password=password,
                                        database=db_name, host=host, max_size=1000)

def create_app():

    app = FastAPI()
    db = Database()

    @app.on_event("startup")
    async def startup():
        await db.create_pool()

    
    @app.post('/api')
    async def insert_db(request: Request):
        data = ...

        df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
        tuples = [tuple(x) for x in df.values]
        connection = await db.pool.acquire()

        s = await connection.copy_records_to_table(table, schema_name=schema, records = tuples, columns = list(df.columns), timeout = 10)
        return s

    return app

app = create_app()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=3000)
```

**Here the logs from Apache Benchmark**

```
$ ab -n 200 -c 20  -T "application/json" -p body.json   http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/mt_retailprice
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1879490 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking 127.0.0.1 (be patient)
Completed 100 requests
Completed 200 requests
Finished 200 requests


Server Software:        gunicorn
Server Hostname:        127.0.0.1
Server Port:            5000

Document Path:          /api/mt_retailprice
Document Length:        60 bytes

Concurrency Level:      20
Time taken for tests:   12.372 seconds
Complete requests:      200
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      42600 bytes
Total body sent:        137800
HTML transferred:       12000 bytes
Requests per second:    16.17 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       1237.222 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       61.861 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          3.36 [Kbytes/sec] received
                        10.88 kb/s sent
                        14.24 kb/s total
```

I have such error when make more requests. For example

```
ab -n 300 -c 20  -T "application/json" -p body.json 
http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/mt_retailprice
```

Anyone know what's this error about ? can't find anything.

```
INFO:     127.0.0.1:50600 - "POST /api/
HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dmitry/anaconda3/envs/nova/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/httptools_impl.py", line 372, in run_asgi
    result = await app(self.scope, self.receive, self.send)
  File "/Users/dmitry/anaconda3/envs/nova/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 75, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/dmitry/anaconda3/envs/nova/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 270, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/dmitry/anaconda3/envs/nova/lib/python3.7/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 124, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/dmitry/anaconda3/envs/nova/lib/python3.7/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 184, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/Users/dmitry/anaconda3/envs/nova/lib/python3.7/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 162, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "/Users/dmitry/anaconda3/envs/nova/lib/python3.7/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 75, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/Users/dmitry/anaconda3/envs/nova/lib/python3.7/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 64, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/Users/dmitry/anaconda3/envs/nova/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 21, in __call__
    raise e
  File "/Users/dmitry/anaconda3/envs/nova/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 18, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/dmitry/anaconda3/envs/nova/lib/python3.7/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 680, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/dmitry/anaconda3/envs/nova/lib/python3.7/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 275, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/dmitry/anaconda3/envs/nova/lib/python3.7/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 65, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "/Users/dmitry/anaconda3/envs/nova/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 232, in app
    dependant=dependant, values=values, is_coroutine=is_coroutine
  File "/Users/dmitry/anaconda3/envs/nova/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 160, in run_endpoint_function
    return await dependant.call(**values)
  File "app_test.py", line 49, in insert_db
    connection = await db.pool.acquire()
  File "/Users/dmitry/anaconda3/envs/nova/lib/python3.7/site-packages/asyncpg/pool.py", line 842, in _acquire
    return await _acquire_impl()
  File "/Users/dmitry/anaconda3/envs/nova/lib/python3.7/site-packages/asyncpg/pool.py", line 827, in _acquire_impl
    proxy = await ch.acquire()  # type: PoolConnectionProxy
  File "/Users/dmitry/anaconda3/envs/nova/lib/python3.7/site-packages/asyncpg/pool.py", line 141, in acquire
    await self.connect()
  File "/Users/dmitry/anaconda3/envs/nova/lib/python3.7/site-packages/asyncpg/pool.py", line 133, in connect
    self._con = await self._pool._get_new_connection()
  File "/Users/dmitry/anaconda3/envs/nova/lib/python3.7/site-packages/asyncpg/pool.py", line 532, in _get_new_connection
    record_class=self._record_class,
  File "/Users/dmitry/anaconda3/envs/nova/lib/python3.7/site-packages/asyncpg/connect_utils.py", line 781, in _connect_addr
    return await __connect_addr(params, timeout, True, *args)
  File "/Users/dmitry/anaconda3/envs/nova/lib/python3.7/site-packages/asyncpg/connect_utils.py", line 833, in __connect_addr
    tr, pr = await compat.wait_for(connector, timeout=timeout)
  File "/Users/dmitry/anaconda3/envs/nova/lib/python3.7/site-packages/asyncpg/compat.py", line 66, in wait_for
    return await asyncio.wait_for(fut, timeout)
  File "/Users/dmitry/anaconda3/envs/nova/lib/python3.7/asyncio/tasks.py", line 442, in wait_for
    return fut.result()
  File "/Users/dmitry/anaconda3/envs/nova/lib/python3.7/site-packages/asyncpg/connect_utils.py", line 695, in _create_ssl_connection
    host, port)
  File "uvloop/loop.pyx", line 1978, in create_connection
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Comment: This is an issue with DNS resolution usually (in particular on Mac OS X apparently); could be that one of the connections in pool fails to connect when it is acquired (and since the connections gets reused, you don't get the error before a certain load factor). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39970606/gaierror-errno-8-nodename-nor-servname-provided-or-not-known-with-macos-sie

Comment: Thank you for response. I've tried this, didn't work. Still under load 300 requests have this problem. My postgres is in AWS. Maybe AWS do something with DNS ?

Comment: You still seem to be running the code under os x, so you can try adding the host and its ip to /etc/hosts to avoid having to look it up on DNS. It might not be the actual issue, but the error message seems to indicate that name resolving fails in some way (you can use something like Wireshark to see what's exactly happening on a lower level, but if you're not familiar with network packets and what they mean, that might be a bit hard to parse out)

Comment: You mean add host and ip of AWS postgres instance to os x /etc/hosts, correct ?

Comment: Correct, that way you never reach out to DNS; it gets resolved locally. See if that fixes antyhing.

Comment: Hello. Yes, problem was DNS, now it works. Thank you for your help. Will post answer